# invalid task with maven

Tags: maven-2, installation

I´m trying to installing maven from Linux command line with a following command:

```
/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn -r -Dclient=HSH -Dmaven.test skip=true install
```

however I keep getting the this:

```
Invalid task 'skip=true': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
```

what should I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

i.e. you're missing a '.' before the `skip`

Comment: great it seems to be working. I´ll accept the answer as soon as possible